# justify_days working issue in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I  execute the justify_days() in postgres sql

```
  SELECT    justify_days(interval '100 month')
```

output

"8 years 4 mons"

But I am using subquery instead of 100

`SELECT  justify_days(interval '(SELECT 100) month')` 
it shows an error

How can I fix it?

Comment: What purpose does this subquery serve?

Comment: What you're expecting ?. why `(SELECT 100)` is coming in that function?This question seems unclear for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
 
`select 100` returns `100` as *integer* datatype, So you need to cast it as *interval* and concatenate like below

```
select justify_days(cast((select 100)||' month' as interval))
```

Result:

```
justify_days
interval
--------------
8 years 4 mons
```

FYI,

```
select cast((select 100)||' month' as interval)
```

gives the same output
Result:

```
    justify_days
    interval
    --------------
    8 years 4 mons
```